# After upgrading iPython to Jupyter, %pylab halts with strange error message

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I just upgraded iPython to Jupyter and wanted to check one of my graphs again to confirm everything was working. It wasn't...

In first line where I have this command

```
%pylab
```

And the result is a long list of error messages, like you see below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4ab7ec3413a5> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('pylab')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-    packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2334         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2335         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2336         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2337 
   2338     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2255                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2256             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2258             return result
   2259 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in pylab(self, line)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in pylab(self, line)
    154             import_all = not args.no_import_all
    155  
--> 156         gui, backend, clobbered = self.shell.enable_pylab(args.gui, import_all=import_all)
    157         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    158         print ("Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all, welcome_message)
   3169         from IPython.core.pylabtools import import_pylab
   3170 
-> 3171         gui, backend = self.enable_matplotlib(gui)
   3172 
   3173         # We want to prevent the loading of pylab to pollute the user's

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3118         """
   3119         from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 3120         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   3121 
   3122         if gui != 'inline':

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    237     """
    238 
--> 239     import matplotlib
    240 
    241     if gui and gui != 'auto':

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
   1129 
   1130 # this is the instance used by the matplotlib classes
-> 1131 rcParams = rc_params()
   1132 
   1133 if rcParams['examples.directory']:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params(fail_on_error)
    973         return ret
    974 
--> 975     return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
    976 
    977 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error, use_default_template)
   1098         parameters specified in the file. (Useful for updating dicts.)
   1099     """
-> 1100     config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1101 
   1102     if not use_default_template:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1016     cnt = 0
   1017     rc_temp = {}
-> 1018     with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
   1019         try:
   1020             for line in fd:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
     57     def __enter__(self):
     58         try:
---> 59             return next(self.gen)
     60         except StopIteration:
     61             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _open_file_or_url(fname)
    998     else:
    999         fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
-> 1000         encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
   1001         if encoding is None:
   1002             encoding = "utf-8"

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/locale.py in getdefaultlocale(envvars)
    554     else:
    555         localename = 'C'
--> 556     return _parse_localename(localename)
    557   
    558 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/locale.py in _parse_localename(localename)
    482     elif code == 'C':
    483         return None, None  
    --> 484     raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
    485 
    486 def _build_localename(localetuple):

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

I am running this on a Mac OSX 10.11.1 and my Python is version 3.4.1.

Really strange - everything was working perfectly before I upgraded to Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just found the solution. Very strange problem - maybe this should be added to the installation guide for Jupyter?

I found the solution [here](https://coderwall.com/p/-k_93g/mac-os-x-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-in-python).

Add the following lines to the `.bash_profile` and then `$source .bash_profile` to get it activated:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And that did the job ... for me at least.